# Can I use the composite video connecor to send video INTO the Raspberry PI?

Tags: video, camera, streaming-video, composite-video

I am looking to convert video from an analogue surveillance camera (w. BNC connector) into a digital format using a Raspberry PI. I was wondering first if the composite video connector would allow me to accept video into the PI..?

If not, can anyone recommend a board or hack to achieve the same thing?

**NOTE**: This is for an existing environment, so changing the cameras is not an option.

**UPDATE**: The intention is to have video coming into this device from the analogue cameras, then back out of the device and into a DVR so the device would be used as a sort of proxy.

Appreciate your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sorry, you cannot use composite video connector for video input, and using analog camera also seems very problematic. I'd recommend to get a cheap web-camera, 1280x720 should be available for less than $15 at any shop, connect it to the USB connector and enjoy!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. USB isn't an option as this is a retro-fit for an existing environment.

Comment: I'll mark this answer as correct as it does answer the original question. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a USB tuner to capture Video in.

[Please check here for compatibility](http://elinux.org/RPi_VerifiedPeripherals#USB_TV_Tuners_and_DVB_devices)

Just make sure to get one that has the extra inputs for SVideo and Analoque input, as well as the terrestrial input.

[image]

Comment: Yes thanks, we have one of these, the problem is that these cost typically around twice the price of a Raspberry PI, whereas an HD camera costs around half the price of the unit!! Seems crazy to me. Just wondering if there is another option.

Comment: Why not just use the HD Cmaera module then? Its not great to set up streaming... but a bit of work and it actually works like a really nice IP Camera

Comment: The "customer" has already invested in cameras before we came along. Otherwise I would have absolutely done this!

Comment: Has he also invested in all the Raspberries? If not. buy a a CCTV capture card instead and use a proper Linux Distro or Windows machine.

Comment: Sorry for the moving goal-posts but I was also hoping to be able to use the device as some sort of proxy so the video can come back out of this device and into the customer's own DVR..?

Comment: SO you want to the Pi to re stream to video to the DVR? Over Wifi.. Lan? It is possible but its not that easy :( Especially that you need a capture card to do it which makes it not feasible.I know personally how nice it sounds to do everything using the Pi but you should accept that the Pi is not a good option here. There is dedicated hardware to convert Analag to Digital video over Wifi, LAN, etc and it will work much better.